# ImportError: cannot import name _imagingtk

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am using python 2.7.6 and I am trying to implement code on https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c to get a slideshow. I have installed required packages for pillow (tcl/tk, jpeg, zlib, image, libpng) but when I try to run I am getting error below. A window opens but it is only a gray window without any image in it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 536, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/home/canburak/Desktop/SocialSlideShow/slideshow27.py", line 55, in _slideshow
    self.show_image()
  File "/home/canburak/Desktop/SocialSlideShow/slideshow27.py", line 76, in show_image
    self._photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.paste(image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 180, in paste
    from PIL import _imagingtk
ImportError: cannot import name _imagingtk
```

I am a newbie on python, how can I solve this problem.

Comment: if you are using windows uninstall `pillow` and reinstall from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow) or for ubuntu use this `sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk`.

Comment: which version of PIL module are you using ?

Comment: have you tried rebuild [pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/322)

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 as OS. I tried to install python-imaging-tk. It did not work either, I am using Pillow 3.2.0. When I search for rebuilding a package in ubuntu solutions always include some changes in source code then compile, is there anyway I can just rebuild the existing package, or should I get the source and then compile it?

Comment: I tried classic way to rebuild a package from this link, still no solution. http://askubuntu.com/questions/81870/how-to-download-modify-build-and-install-a-debian-source-package

Comment: Did you try this pip `install -I --no-cache-dir Pillow`.

Comment: I guess my pip version is different than yours, it says "no such option: --no-cache-dir"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the present pil/pillow packages and then try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
```